# Spyder IDE Editor Colors

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

[image: Editor]

In Anaconda Spyder is there a way to make the editor assign colors like in this IDE? It would be very helpful for learning and keeping track of variables.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) It's not possible right now, but it will be in Spyder 5, to be released next year.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! In "Tools" click "Preferences" and then "Syntax Colouring". You will find an option "create new scheme" along with other preset themes. We can manually change the color scheme for `comments`, `string`, `number`,`keyword` ,`builtin`, `definitions` and `instances` in "create new scheme" by changing the color code.

[image: Image of Color scheme editor]

Comment: It is activated but doesn't show anything past "from", import, def

Comment: We can manually change the color scheme for comments, string, number,keyword ,builtin, definitions and instances in "create new scheme" by changing the color code.